# How to subscribe different channels by a specification?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am looking for a switching operator in Spring IntegrationFlows. I need to subscribe to a channel based on the property that user can decide.

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(
                        subscription -> {
                            if (true)//user is going to decide this.
                                subscription.subscribe(flow1());
                            else
                                subscription.subscribe(flow2());
                        }
                )
                .get();
    }
```

This is my basic implementation, but it doesn't work. Is a feature for that ?

Comment: Is that runtime user property, message-based? Or do you have it at configuration phase, so you can configure it only once?

Comment: @ArtemBilan sorry, i forgot to mention. It is not in the runtime. user going to set in application.properties .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about an `application.properties`, then there is nothing more than a conditions in configuration. See a `@Value` injection into a bean definition  method: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-value-annotations

So, something like this for your flow bean:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(Value("${your.prop}") String propValue) {
```

Than you indeed can do that `if...else` insider a `subscription` lambda.

Another way is to use a `@ConditionalOnProperty` from Spring Boot and have those `flow1()` and `flow2()` be as conditional bean.

Then you can inject an `IntegrationFlow` into this your `flow()` bean - same method argument injection technique, - and only one of conditional beans is going to be available for you.

In two words: everything what you can do with Spring dependency injection can be used when you declare `IntegrationFlow` beans.